# Trying to use Automapper to Map Dictionary to Object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following DataContainer:

```
public class FlatData {
  public Dictionary<string, object> Fields {get;set;}
}
```

I want to use AutoMapper to Map the Values within "Fields" to the Properties of the following class:

```
public class Target {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description { get;set; }
   public int Id { get;set; }
}
```

Now the FlatData has the following Values inside "Fields":

```
"Id" -> 12
"Name" -> "Jean Luc"
"Description" -> "Captain"
```

I wrote the following Extension to map this:

```
 public static class MappingExtensions
    {
        public static T ConvertUsingFlatData<T>(ResolutionContext ctx, FlatData data)
        {
            var dest = ctx.DestinationValue;

            foreach (var field in data.Fields)
            {
                var target = ctx.DestinationType.GetProperty(field.Key);

                target.SetValue(dest, field.Value);
            }

            return (T)dest;
        }
    }
```

Now when I try to read and map the data

```
  public Myrepo(MyActions actions)
        {
            _actions = actions;
            _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<FlatData, Target>()
                    .ConvertUsing((ctx, s) => MappingExtensions.ConvertUsingFlatData<Target>(ctx, s));
            }).CreateMapper();
        }
public IEnumerable<Target> GetAll() {
  return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Target>>(_actions.Select());
}
```

I receive an error. I can debug inside the static Mapping extension and can see that "dataRow" has all the required data, but that **"ctx.DestinationValue" is null**.  (ctx.DestinationType seems to be correct)

(_action.Select()) returns an List of FlatData()-Type)

Comment: Automapper will try to map the name of the properties to matching properties in the target class. I think you will have to access the parent and specifically write the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see `DestinationValue` property as the value passed during the map (when you use `Map(source, destination)` overload), but in your case you're not passing any. This is a known issue, you can read more [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/873).

But in your case you can't pass a destination value since your are mapping a collection, but you can try something like this:

```
public static T ConvertUsingFlatData<T>(ResolutionContext ctx, FlatData data) 
{
    var dest = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    foreach (var field in data.Fields)
    {
        var target = ctx.DestinationType.GetProperty(field.Key);

        target.SetValue(dest, field.Value);

    }

    return dest;
}
```